# Connect to an Oracle database with SQL Server 2000 Reporting Services?

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, sql-server-2000

I am trying to create a report in SSRS2000 that will query an ORACLE database and pass one parameter, I am getting the following error message:

ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number 
But have been unable to find much help elsewhere on the web with this error code

I was hoping that this would be fairly simple to do, does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to accept some Answer in order to show this question as "Answered" and you can't accept your own, so it might as well be this one.

Guys, I Swear I'm not trolling for rep, I don't even know what the proper term for that is. But if I mark it as Wiki, I won't right? So I did.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the parameter had to be named Parameter1 for this to work, and that the dba had to correct a connection issue!